# How to make the BibTeX reference list visible in a LaTeX document

Tags: bibliographies

Im very new at LaTeX and I would appreciate some help solving this problem. I have created a BibTeX file containing all references to a document. In this text file BibTeX items are inserted and no other text are written, for instance @article{...}. When I call for this bib file from the main.tex file I use the commands:

```
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{thebibliography}
```

Now to my question. All i get when I compile this main.tex is the title (bibliography) for this chapter, otherwise the textfield is blank. Is this error occurring because I should write anything in the bib file or have I missed any lines in the main.tex file.

Answer (score 8):

If you want everything included, you can use

```
\nocite{*}
```

Answer (score 4):

By default, only those references are listed in the bibliography which also appear in the main text, so maybe you do not reference your sources so far?

Comment: Hi, 
This was actually the case. I just wanted to look at the bibliography before I started to use it as a reference. 

Thanks for the quick reply.

Comment: To include references that have not been cited, you could use the \nocite{refid} command e.g. just before the bibliography!